# What does it mean to call a function without being bound to an identifier

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I understand Lambda expressions in the sense of:

```
    delegate int del(int i);
    static void Main()
    {
        del myDelegate = x => x * x;
        int j = myDelegate(2);
        Console.WriteLine(j);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It's actually quite neat, and something I will use again, however I read this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => Print("Hello from t!"));
        t.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

I can't quite figure out what `() =>` means, after googling I found out that I am (according to wikipedia) using an anonymous function that is undefinded (?) and/or not bound to an identifier.

Now, I ask what does that mean? Am I even doing what I just stated?

Comment: It's exactly what you have said it is.  It's an anonymous method.  A method without a name (or, to use an equivalent term, without an identifier).  What about that is confusing?

Comment: Why to declare a delegate when you can use `Func<int,int> del = x => x * x;`

Comment: @abatishchev - I'm sure it was just an arbitrary example, no need to nitpick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`() =>` is the start of a lambda expression that doesn't have any parameters. It's important to understand that a lambda expression can't exist in a vacuum - it's always part of a conversion to either a delegate type or an expression tree type.

In this case, this is being used as an argument to the [`Thread` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you look at the thread constructor, there are four overloads, two of which have a single parameter. One takes a [`ThreadStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter, the other takes a [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter. These are both delegate types, but `ParameterizedThreadStart` has a parameter whereas `ThreadStart` doesn't.

So there's an implicit conversion from your parameterless lambda expression to `ThreadStart`, but not to `ParameterizedThreadStart`, so it will call the overload taking a `ThreadStart`.

So it's equivalent to:

```
ThreadStart tmp = () => Print("Hello from t!");
Thread t = new Thread(tmp);
```

To use a `ParameterizedThreadStart`, there are three options:

```
// x is inferred to be type object
ParameterizedThreadStart tmp = x => Print("Hello from t!");
// The same, but with brackets around the parameter
ParameterizedThreadStart tmp = (x) => Print("Hello from t!");
// Fully explicit parameter list
ParameterizedThreadStart tmp = (object x) => Print("Hello from t!");
```

(Again, these could be inlined into the `Thread` constructor call, and the compiler would infer which constructor was intended.)

Answer (score 1):

It means it's an anonymous function (a lambda expression) without any parameters.  Normally you would need parameters to a lambda to do something with it.  But, if you don't need any parameters, like in your Print statement, then you can call it with an empty parameter set.  It makes more sense when you realize that when you have only one parameter, the parenthesis are optional.  But with multiple parameters, or no parameters, you need them.

ie:

```
(foo, bar) => foo.X + bar.y
```

or

```
() => DoSomething()
```

Comment: Quick terminology pedantry: it's not an anonymous method, it's a lambda expression. That's an anonymous *function*, but an anonymous *method* would be `delegate { ... }`

Comment: @JonSkeet - I am suitably chastised.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`()` means, that the method has zero input arguments.

So the second example is the same as:

```
static void Main()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Foo);
    t.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void Foo()
{
    Print("Hello from t!");
}

static void Print(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

So in the first example `x => x * x;` is equivalent to `(x) => x * x`, meaning this anonymous method has 1 input argument.